# How to compile string of coffeescript code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

So let's say I have a string of coffeescript code, in a javascript file on nodejs. How could I convert this string into javascript, without using the terminal? I have tried [coffeescript-compiler](https://www.npmjs.org/package/coffeescript-compiler), but it gave me an error about a closed socket. I have coffeescript installed globally and coffee-script compiler installed locally.

Edit: Here is the code:

```
var Compiler = require('coffeescript-compiler');
var cc = new Compiler();

cc.compile('a = 5', function (status, output) {
    if (status === 0) {
        // JavaScript available as a string in the `output` variable
    }
});
```

And here is the error it throws:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; //unhandled 'error' event

Error: This socket is closed.
    at Socket._write (net.js:637:19)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:225:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:215:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:182:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:615:40)
    at doCompile (D:\TSA\App\node_modules\coffeescript-compiler\Compiler.js:33:15)
    at Compiler.compile (D:\TSA\App\node_modules\coffeescript-compiler\Compiler.js:46:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\TSA\App\coffeescript.js:4:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use for `coffeescript-compiler`? It is definitely the thing to use.

Answer (score 2):

The CoffeeScript package itself provides a compiler function, so for a simple use case like yours it's even easier than using `coffee-compiler`. You can get what you want with something like this:

```
var CoffeeScript = require('coffee-script');
var compiledJS = CoffeeScript.compile('a = 5');
```

Answer (score 0):

The CoffeeScript compiler will return you a regular javascript string, but then you need to run that through something else to require it.

```
// First the coffee-script string needs to be converted to valid javascript
function requireCoffeeScript(src, filename) {
  var script = require("coffee-script").compile(src, {filename});
  return requireJSFromString(script, filename);
}

// Now the valid javascript string can be 'required' and the exports returned
function requireJSFromString(src, filename) {
  var m = new module.constructor();
  m.paths = module.paths;
  m._compile(src, filename);
  return m.exports;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use this [online converter](http://www.compileonline.com/try_coffeescript_online.php).

Or, the CoffeeScript(http://coffeescript.org/) homepage has a tab: "Try CoffeeScript", where you could paste your CoffeeScript code and see its equivalent in JavaScript.

Comment: No, I mean something like a function I can call to compile coffeescript, like:  `var code = compile('a="foo"')`, where code would equal `'var a = "foo"'`.